# set clock of multiple county by java script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to set clock of multiple country by JavaScript:

Example :

```
     U.S.A      India      Australia    Spain    
     10:20:23   15:32:23   19:36:41     15:63:20
```

I want set this clock live in a page.

I use PHP in My page

Comment: I wonder how it can be 15:63:20 in Span, hint : search your first line in Google, check first 5 links

Comment: this is just for an example dear @valli-R

Comment: @Toms : Example shouldn't be wrong as they are assumptions for your QUESTION...

Comment: Please understand the difference between Java and JavaScript. Then tell us which you want.

Comment: have a look here: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: also what have you tried so far??

Comment: this is fantastic idea for making a multiple clock for multiple county in a page

Comment: @Doers this is fantastic comment for making funnies a answer in a stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing should be the that one Date object is created per country and it is created once. I'm not exactly sure what the php code should be - either use the time provided by your server and add/subtract time, or check [here](http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php) how to get time from time server.

html:

```
<div id="spain"></div>
<div id="jamaica"></div>​
```

js:

```
function zeroLead(i) { return i < 10 ? ("0" + i) : i; }
function start ( dateStr, where ) {
    var today = new Date ( dateStr );
    return function() {
        document.getElementById(where).innerHTML =
        zeroLead ( today.getHours()   ) + ":" +
        zeroLead ( today.getMinutes() ) + ":" +
        zeroLead ( today.getSeconds() );
        today.setMilliseconds ( 1001 );
    }
}

// here you set date with php
// date("F j, Y G:i:s");
var Spain = start   ( "May 11, 2012 21:13:00", "spain"   );
var Jamaica = start ( "May 11, 2012 21:43:00", "jamaica" );

setInterval( Spain,   1000 );
setInterval( Jamaica, 1000 );​
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgSLr/) and [live demo](http://zdravko.genov.me/demo/Multiple-clocks.php) with php.

Comment: thanks @Bakudan You save my day, i give `up point` with `accept answer`.